# How to switch to getDerivedStateToProps without getting loading is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to eventually refactor this lifecycle method:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const validationComplete = this.props.loading && !nextProps.loading;

    if (validationComplete && nextProps.userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice) {
      if (nextProps.userAddressIsValidForVoterVoice) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Questionnaire");
      } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("InvalidHomeAddress");
      }
    }
  }
```

to this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
    const validationComplete = this.props.loading && !nextProps.loading;

    if (validationComplete && nextProps.userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice) {
      if (nextProps.userAddressIsValidForVoterVoice) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Questionnaire");
      } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("InvalidHomeAddress");
      }
    }
  }
```

However, if I do that, I will get `loading` is undefined. How could I refactor this in such a way that this would not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot do it with `getDerivedStateFromProps` because you cannot access `this` in a static function. As per [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) you should use `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const {navigation, loading, userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice, userAddressIsValidForVoterVoice} = this.props
    const validationComplete = prevProps.loading && !loading;
    if (validationComplete && userEmailIsValidForVoterVoice) {
      if (userAddressIsValidForVoterVoice) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        navigation.navigate("Questionnaire");
      } else {
        navigation.navigate("InvalidHomeAddress");
      }
    }
}
```